# SdkClientException: Unable to instantiate. Listed request handler ('software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.internal.MessageMD5ChecksumInterceptor')

Tags: maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to build SQSAsyncClient in Flink maven project. Following is my pom.xml. I can see sqs aws sdk-v2 package is correctly added in jar but I am getting following SDKClientException on job start. I have used maven-shaded-plugin to include sqs dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connectors</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>flink-connector-aws-kinesis-streams</artifactId>
    <name>Flink : Connectors : Amazon Kinesis Data Streams</name>
    <properties>
        <aws.sdk.version>2.17.247</aws.sdk.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-aws-base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Table API dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-aws-base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kinesis table factory testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ArchUit test dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-architecture-tests-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>shade-flink</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadeTestJar>false</shadeTestJar>
                            <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
                            <artifactSet combine.children="append">
                                <includes>
                                    <include>software.amazon.awssdk:*</include>
                                    <include>io.netty:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>

                            <relocations combine.children="override">
                                   <relocation>
                                       <pattern>software.amazon</pattern>
                                       <shadedPattern>org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon</shadedPattern>
                                   </relocation>
                                   <relocation>
                                       <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                                       <shadedPattern>org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.io.netty</shadedPattern>
                                  </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                           <filters>
                                  <filter>
                                          <artifact>software.amazon.awssdk:*</artifact>
                                          <excludes>
                                              <exclude>META-INF/services/**</exclude>
                                          </excludes>
                                  </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>


                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Exception:

org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to instantiate request handler chain for client. Listed request handler ('software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.internal.MessageMD5ChecksumInterceptor') does not implement the interface org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptor API.
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.createExecutionInterceptor(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:134)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.createExecutionInterceptorFromResource(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:95)

```
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.createExecutionInterceptorsFromClasspath(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.getInterceptors(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:51)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.DefaultSqsBaseClientBuilder.finalizeServiceConfiguration(DefaultSqsBaseClientBuilder.java:57)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeChildConfiguration(AwsDefaultClientBuilder.java:176)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.asyncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:204)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.DefaultSqsAsyncClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultSqsAsyncClientBuilder.java:28)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.DefaultSqsAsyncClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultSqsAsyncClientBuilder.java:22)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:145)
at org.apache.flink.connector.kinesis.sink.SQSPublisherSink.open(SQSPublisherSink.java:47)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:100)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.open(StreamSink.java:46)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:726)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:702)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:669)
at 
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kinesis.sink.SQSPublisherSink.close(SQSPublisherSink.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.closeFunction(FunctionUtils.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.close(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.closeAllOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.closeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:1025)
    at org.apache.flink.util.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:255)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.AutoCloseableRegistry.doClose(AutoCloseableRegistry.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.util.AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.close(AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.java:127)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.cleanUp(StreamTask.java:943)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.lambda$restoreAndInvoke$0(Task.java:917)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:917)
    ... 3 more
```

SQSPublisher.java

```
package org.apache.flink.connector.kinesis.sink;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.Watermark;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.FunctionInitializationContext;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.FunctionSnapshotContext;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.NettyNioAsyncHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;


/**
 * Implementation of SQS Publisher Sink.
 */
public class SQSPublisherSink<OUT> extends RichSinkFunction<OUT>
        implements CheckpointedFunction {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSPublisherSink.class);

    private final String sqsUrl;
  
    private transient SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient;

    private transient ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public SQSPublisherSink(String sqsUrl) {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink, url - {}", sqsUrl);
        this.sqsUrl = sqsUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink open, parameters - {}", parameters);

        sqsAsyncClient = SqsAsyncClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .httpClientBuilder(NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder())
                .build();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink open - {}", sqsAsyncClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void snapshotState(FunctionSnapshotContext context) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink snapshotState - {}", context);
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink initializeState - {}", context);
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(OUT value, Context context) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink invoke - {}, context - {}", value, context);
        String messageBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = SendMessageRequest.builder()
                .queueUrl(sqsUrl)
               .messageBody(messageBody)
               .build();
        sqsAsyncClient.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest).get();

    }

    @Override
    public void writeWatermark(Watermark watermark) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink writeWatermark - {}", watermark);
        super.writeWatermark(watermark);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink finish");
        super.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("SQSPublisherSink close : {} ", sqsAsyncClient);
        sqsAsyncClient.close();
    }
}
```